# How can I iterate through a javascript array and call a function that updates the same array?

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

```
var test.qs =
[
 {"answer":null,
  "testQuestionId":710
  "synchronized":true},
 {"answer":null,
  "testQuestionId":711
  "synchronized":false
]
```

I would like to call a function on all the array objects that have the syncronized property equal to false like this:

```
if (!test.qs[x].synchronized) {
    httpPutTestQuestion(number)
    .success(function (data) {
        test.qs[x].synchronized = true;
    })
}
```

But how can I do this as if I put this into a for loop then when the function returns I won't still have the value x?

Comment: You missed the closing brace for second array record, just FYI :)

Comment: ... and a couple of commas. Also `var test.qs` is not valid javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for you.

```
test.qs.forEach(function (q) {
if (!q.synchronized) {
    httpPutTestQuestion(number)
    .success(function (data) {
        q.synchronized = true;
    })
}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the plain old loop, like this

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < qs.length; i += 1) {
    if (qs[i].synchronized === false) {
        httpPutTestQuestion(number)
            .success(function (data) {
                test.qs[x].synchronized = true;
            })
        };
    }
}
```

You can get the length of the array with the `length` property. Also note that, the variable names inJavaScript cannot have `.` in them. So,

```
var test.qs = ....
```

will fail.